# Using multiple forEach chained into each other and iterating over a single array, Need an equivalent method to handle the same without forEach looping

Tags: arrays, angular, object, foreach

My array contains multiple arrays and to access the objects, I have used multiple forEach. How do I handle using multiple foreach loops?
Kindly suggest an equivalent method to avoid this chaining.
See the below snippet and suggest a better solution to optimize my code.

```js
var v = [
    {
        "company_name": "Apple",
        "company_code": "AP",
        "states": [
            {
                "state_name": "California",
                "state_code": "CA",
                "locations": [
                    {
                        "location_name": "USA - New York",
                        "location_code": "US - NY"
                    },
          {
                        "location_name": "USA - San Francisco",
                        "location_code": "US - SF"
                    }
                ]
            },
        {
                "state_name": "Rajasthan",
                "state_code": "RJ",
                "locations": [
                    {
                        "location_name": "Udaipur",
                        "location_code": "UDR"
                    },
          {
                        "location_name": "Jaipur",
                        "location_code": "JP"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]  
 
var AllData=[]

for (let i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
  const data = v[i];
  //console.log(data);

    data.states.forEach((state) => {
      state.locations.forEach((location) => {
        const ELEMENT_DATA = {
          companyname: data.company_name,
          statename: state.state_name,
          locationname: location.location_name,
        };
        AllData.push(ELEMENT_DATA);
      });
    });
  
}
console.log(AllData);
```

Comment: What´s the problem with your code?

Answer (score 1):

Not really an optimisation, more of a readability improvement:

```js
const arr = v.map(data =>
  data.states.map(state =>
    state.locations.map(location =>
      ({
        companyname: data.company_name,
        statename: state.state_name,
        locationname: location.location_name
      })
    )
  )
);
```

Check the following snippet to see if the output is the same.

```js
var v = [{
  "company_name": "Apple",
  "company_code": "AP",
  "states": [{
      "state_name": "California",
      "state_code": "CA",
      "locations": [{
          "location_name": "USA - New York",
          "location_code": "US - NY"
        },
        {
          "location_name": "USA - San Francisco",
          "location_code": "US - SF"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "state_name": "Rajasthan",
      "state_code": "RJ",
      "locations": [{
          "location_name": "Udaipur",
          "location_code": "UDR"
        },
        {
          "location_name": "Jaipur",
          "location_code": "JP"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}]

const arr = v.map(data =>
  data.states.map(state =>
    state.locations.map(location =>
      ({
        companyname: data.company_name,
        statename: state.state_name,
        locationname: location.location_name
      })
    )
  )
);
console.log(arr)
```

This is basically your code, looping on each of the properties, it is just more easy to read.